# How to list s3fs mounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3fs

How can I list the [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) mounts that exist on an ubuntu system?
I'd like to know to which bucket each mount is mapped.

Specifically, I have a specific mount (e.g. ~/s3/mymount), and would like to know to which S3 bucket its mapped.

Answer (score 7):

> I'd like to know to which bucket each mount is mapped.

```
# ps -ef | grep s3fs
root      9273     1  0 Feb12 ?        00:34:52 s3fs bucket1 /mnt/p1
root     23130     1  0 Feb18 ?        00:53:10 s3fs bucket2 /mnt/p2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can view s3 mounts with the `mount` command:

```
[user@hostname ~]$ mount | grep ^s3fs
s3fs on /mnt/point type fuse.s3fs (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0)
```

If you don't see it here it is probably not mounted.

A related item you will see in the mount output is `fusectl`:

```
[user@hostname ~]$ mount | grep ^fusectl
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
```

This is a related service that is used to mount the s3 bucket but does not indicate if an s3 bucket is currently mounted. Only that you could mount it with fusectl

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it show up in the "mount" command?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Wait, actually I see this in mount: `fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
` ... but I still don't know what to make of it.